# BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) error with X11 library

Tags: c, x11

Code below will throw Bad Match error, from XChangeWindowAttributes function call.

I did some research on this, the Bad Match error only threw when the window that passed as parameter is input only, but I'm pretty sure I set the MenuModeWindow to be InputOutput. How can I fix this problem?

```
MenuModeWindow = XCreateWindow(
        BOTIFDisplay,   /* display */
        BOTIFParentWindow,  /* parent window */
        xstart - 144/* 155 */,
        ystart,     /* top left y */
        winwidth + winwidthalter,       /* win width */
        winheight,      /* win height */
        0,      /* border width */
        CopyFromParent,
        InputOutput,
        CopyFromParent,
        valuemask,
        &winatt);
    if(InBOTIFColor())
        XSetWindowBackground(BOTIFDisplay, MenuModeWindow,
            ParentActiveBackGroundPixel);
    else
        XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(BOTIFDisplay, MenuModeWindow,
            GrayPixMaps[125]);
```

Comment: "but I'm pretty sure" – So first of all, *make* sure. For example, use `xwininfo` on the opened window and look at its class.

Comment: @IngoBürk What if the window didn't open because program crushed because that Bad Match error?

Comment: Remove the offending code temporarily.

Comment: @IngoBürk Hey! I already checked it with XGetWindowAttributes(), and it shows the class is 1, which is InputOutput. Also, this BadMatch error could throw anywhere at anytime, sometime it will throw when you call XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap, sometime it will throw when you trying to find a font by using XLoadQueryFont, sometime it will even throw when you call XGetWindowAttributes...

Comment: @IngoBürk I think I found the problem here, it seems like XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap() only accept either 0 or 1 as it third parameter, which is type as Pixmap, defined as unsigned long. If you pass a value other than 0 or 1, you will get a BadPixMap error or BadMatch error, why this will be the case?

Comment: It should also take a proper Pixmap. 0 and 1 are probably the values for ParentRelative and None. How is GrayPixMaps defined?

Comment: @IngoBürk GrayPixMaps is defined as an array with Pixmap type, Pixmap is defined as XID, and XID is defined as unsigned long.

Comment: I meant actually show the code. It could also be an issue that the depth of the pixmap doesn't match the depth of the window and stuff like that. This typically generates bad matches.